# Make all done org-mode items invisible (collapsed)

Tags: org-mode, todo

How can I make all done (e.g. DONE) org-mode items "invisible"?  I'm using org-mode's "visibility" terminology here, but what I'm referring to is collapsing (folding) those items closed, not making them literally invisible.  I don't want to use org's sparse trees for this.

I have multiple custom done states (including SKIP, for example).  I want items to be collapsed if they are in any of those states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
(defun my/org-get-folded-state ()
    (cond
        ((not (or (org-at-item-p) (org-at-heading-p)))
            'not-at-node)
        ((org-before-first-heading-p)
            'not-at-node)
        (t
            (let (eoh eol eos has-children children-skipped struct)
                ;; First, determine end of headline (EOH), end of subtree or item
                ;; (EOS), and if item or heading has children (HAS-CHILDREN).
                (save-excursion
                    (if (org-at-item-p)
                        (progn
                            (beginning-of-line)
                            (setq struct (org-list-struct))
                            (setq eoh (point-at-eol))
                            (setq eos (org-list-get-item-end-before-blank (point) struct))
                            (setq has-children (org-list-has-child-p (point) struct)))
                        (org-back-to-heading)
                        (setq eoh (save-excursion (outline-end-of-heading) (point)))
                        (setq eos (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t t)
                                      (when (bolp) (backward-char)) (point)))
                        (setq has-children
                            (or (save-excursion
                                    (let ((level (funcall outline-level)))
                                        (outline-next-heading)
                                        (and (org-at-heading-p t)
                                            (> (funcall outline-level) level))))
                                (save-excursion
                                    (org-list-search-forward (org-item-beginning-re) eos t)))))
                    ;; Determine end invisible part of buffer (EOL)
                    (beginning-of-line 2)
                    (while (and (not (eobp)) ;; this is like `next-line'
                               (get-char-property (1- (point)) 'invisible))
                        (goto-char (next-single-char-property-change (point) 'invisible))
                        (and (eolp) (beginning-of-line 2)))
                    (setq eol (point)))
                (cond
                    ((= eos eoh)
                        'empty-node)
                    ((or (>= eol eos)
                         (not (string-match "\\S-" (buffer-substring eol eos))))
                        'folded)
                    (t
                        'not-folded))))))

(defun my/org-tree-can-fold-p ()
    (not (member (my/org-get-folded-state) (list 'folded 'empty-node))))

(defun my/org-cycle-until-folded ()
    (while (my/org-tree-can-fold-p)
        (org-cycle)))

(defun my/org-hide-done-entries-in-range (start end)
    (save-excursion
        (goto-char end)
        (while (and (outline-previous-heading) (> (point) start))
            (when (org-entry-is-done-p)
                (my/org-cycle-until-folded)))))

(defun my/org-hide-done-entries-in-region (start end)
    (interactive "r")
    (my/org-hide-done-entries-in-range start end))

(defun my/org-hide-done-entries-in-buffer ()
    (interactive)
    (my/org-hide-done-entries-in-range (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you! I added advice to run `my/org-hide-done-entries-in-buffer` after `org-cycle-set-startup-visibility` and it's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can [archive](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-archiving.html) all items you want folded.

Archived items (i.e. items marked with the `ARCHIVE` tag) will always remain folded unless explicitly unfolded via `org-force-cycle-archived` (<kbd>C-TAB</kbd>).

If you want to do a bulk archiving on all DONE items, there is an example [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-mapping-API.html) on how to proceed. Something like the following (untested):

```
(org-map-entries
  '(org-toggle-tag "ARCHIVE" 'on )
  "/+DONE" 'file 'archive 'comment)
```

This adds the ARCHIVE tag to all headings in the file having the DONE state (excluding commented and archived trees).

Comment: Thanks, interesting, though not exactly what I'm looking for: I think I just want to set the folded state as a one-off operation rather than changing the text of the buffer like this.  I think I'll use archiving in some other cases, though, so good to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The following command, minimally tested, will hide/fold all entries marked with one of the DONE keywords:

```
(defun org-fold-all-done-entries ()
  "Close/fold all entries marked DONE."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while (outline-previous-heading)
      (when (org-entry-is-done-p)
        (hide-entry)))))
```

Note that the `outline` commands may be changing prefixes.  If so, you may wish to change the `hide-entry` line to `outline-hide-entry`.

Comment: (hide-entry) doesn't hide the item for me, but (hide-subtree) does.  I would edit the answer but I don't understand what you mean by "changing prefixes"?  Also, in emacs 25 I don't have an outline-hide-entry (nor any functions whose names start with "outline-hide")